# how to make thread handle events?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I've made a bingo game using javafx and multithreading in which there are several players and a cart for each player, each player(cart) is handled by a separate thread which builds the cart and adds it to the main scene.
when a player presses a label in the cart there several things which must be done by the thread.

what is happening with me is the for every cart there is thread but when it comes to handling mouse event it get handled by the same thread for all players which is not supposed to be that way

how can i solve this problem?

here is the run method

```
public void run() { // every thread starts from here
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    synchronized (this) {
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                int num = Generator.Generate();
                MCart[j][k] = num;
                Label textField = this.AddLabel(num, j, k);

                box.add(textField, j, k);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

}
```

and here is the method which trigger the mouseEvent

```
    private synchronized Label AddLabel(int num, int j, int k) {

    Label textField = new Label("" + num);
    textField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    textField.setPrefSize(25, 10);
    textField.setStyle(
            "-fx-pref-width: 2em; -fx-background-color: white; -fx-text-color: black; -fx-border-color:black ;");
    int col = k, Row = j;

    box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    // box.setStyle(" -fx-background-color: skyblue;");
    // box.setPrefSize(230, 150);
    GridPane.setConstraints(textField, j, k);
    textField.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleMouseClick(textField, col, Row));
    return textField;
}
```

and here is the method that handles the mouse event

```
private synchronized void handleMouseClick(Label textField, int col, int Row) {

    long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    textField.setStyle("-fx-text-color: red;");

    Label text = textField;
    text.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("#ff0000"));
    System.out.println("thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + id);
```

}

and here is the output
`thread 20
thread 21
thread 22
thread 23
thread 24
thread 16 16
thread 16 16
thread 16 16`

Comment: Can you share your current code? So that I can suggest edits.

Comment: i have made the changes you asked for,thx

Comment: Why do you think it  is not supposed to be that way? And why is it a problem?

Comment: there is no thread 16, the thread that should handle the mouse click is not thread 16 it supposed to be one of the threads above

Comment: You must not modify the GUI from a background thread. Your `run` method looks like you add `Label`s to a `GridPane` from a background thread which could easily result in problems. Furthermore there doesn't seem to be a longrunning operation involved in your `run` method. I don't see a point in using a seperate thread for running this code. I'd recommend using the JavaFX application thread until you're sure you need to use a seperate thread to prevent the GUI from freezing.

Comment: Your question isn't clear for me but from whatever that I understood, I believe that you created 5 carts( sequentially because of the synchronized keyword). Then you have been adding labels to all the carts(sequentially again with a single thread i., thread-16). Now when you add a label, You want to handle mouse click event to happen asynchronously. With that assumption why don't you call that handlemouseclick event in a seperate thread?

Comment: the handling should be to be handled by the same thread that created the cart and so adding the label should be also,this a course project  and those are the requirement of the game ,otherwise i could do it by the main thread :),thx for your help guys